# REGEXP_EXTRACT in hive to get the substring of a string

Tags: sql, regex, hive

Hi i am new to hive i am using regexp_extract for getting substring from a string

```
my string is '/abc/def/ghi/'
```

how will get abc or def or ghi using regexp_extract function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove leading and trailing `'/'` and use `split()` to get an Array. [split()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) is also using regexp:

```
hive> select split(regexp_replace('/abc/def/ghi/','^/|/$',''),'/')[0];

abc

hive> select split(regexp_replace('/abc/def/ghi/','^/|/$',''),'/')[1];

def

hive> select split(regexp_replace('/abc/def/ghi/','^/|/$',''),'/')[2];

ghi
```

Or in a subquery:

```
hive> select array[0], array[1], array[2] 
      from (select split(regexp_replace('/abc/def/ghi/','^/|/$',''),'/') as array) s;
OK
_c0     _c1     _c2
abc     def     ghi
Time taken: 0.192 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Hi leftjoin, I wanted pattern to be same. Your answer is working for me. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `regexp_extract` by providing a pattern with capture groups targeting what we want to match.  Then, we can specify which group should serve as the replacement.

As an example, to find the content between the second and third path separators, we can try:

```
regexp_extract('/abc/def/ghi/', '/[^/]+/([^/]+).*', 1)
```

Note: The above is untested and may give error should it be necessary to escape the forward slashes.  In that case, use the following:

```
regexp_extract('/abc/def/ghi/', '\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+).*', 1)
```

Comment: Hi Tim i have created a regular expression in oracle i.e. `REGEXP_SUBSTR('/abc/def/ghi/','[^/]*/',1,2)` to get abc and for def `REGEXP_SUBSTR('/abc/def/ghi/','[^/]*/',1,3)` for ghi `REGEXP_SUBSTR('/abc/def/ghi/','[^/]*/',1,4)` i want the same thing in hive....i don't want to change my pattern and can you please explain your regular expression i will really appriciate it.

Comment: Sorry, but your current pattern probably won't work with `regexp_extract` in Hive.  And you should try my answer before you vote to discard it.

Comment: yeah i tried, it is returning `def`. for getting `abc` and `ghi` there will be different pattern used right? can you please explain this `regexp_extract('/abc/def/ghi','\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+).*',1)` it will help me understand it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below would be the query.

```
   hive> select regexp_extract('/abc123./def456./ghi789/', '\/([\\w\\d.]*)\/([\\w\\d.]*)\/([\\w\\d.]*)',1);
OK
abc123.
Time taken: 0.103 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select regexp_extract('/abc123./def456./ghi789/', '\/([\\w\\d.]*)\/([\\w\\d.]*)\/([\\w\\d.]*)',2);
OK
def456.
Time taken: 0.1 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select regexp_extract('/abc123./def456./ghi789/', '\/([\\w\\d.]*)\/([\\w\\d.]*)\/([\\w\\d.]*)',3);
OK
ghi789
Time taken: 0.124 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: What if the characters are not word characters?

Comment: Sir - Have updated the query to include digit and alphanumeric and special character . , we can add additional special character within [] as required

Comment: Or better yet just use `[^\/]` to match any non path separator character.